# Dell XPS 15 L502X hard drive Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, partition-recovery, dell-xps

I have a situation here. I got my new Dell XPS 15 Laptop.

The configuration of hard drive is as below :

- Volume 1: (OEM Partition): 133MB
- Volume 2: OS (C:): 685.25 GB
- Volume
  3: Recovery : 13.25 GB

[image]

Now, **I am trying to re-partition my C Drive** to have a C: drive with 100 GB and a new drive with 585 GB. Earlier, I tried using the Windows 7 Disk Management to shrink and extend the volume. That lead to the OS and hard drive not working. Dell Tech support tried to fix the issue, but they were not able to fix the issue online. Later a Dell Technician arrived my place, and replaced the hard drive with a new hard drive.

**Please help me re-partition the C: Drive with 100 GB, and new D drive with 585 GB**.

**I don't want to lose my Recovery Partition.**

> ***SOLUTION***
>
> As Suggested by [KCotreau](https://superuser.com/users/83981/kcotreau) [below](https://superuser.com/questions/313082/dell-xps-15-l502x-hard-drive-partition/313084#313084) , I have done exactly. I have resized the C drive to 100 GB. And then applied the changes. Windows got restarted. On the boot screen, the partition was taking place. It took around 30 mins ( approx. ). Once after restart, I can see my C drive is 100 GB. Now opened the Easeus again. And created a new partition for the free space ( 585 GB ) this took 10 seconds to create. Here goes the screenshot after partitioning. Thanks to [KCotreau](https://superuser.com/users/83981/kcotreau). You are amazing.

[image]

Comment: Help you do what? I am not sure what you are asking for. You have a new drive with the above disk configuration...what are you trying to do to it? Or you now have an empty drive?

Comment: I am trying to parition. I have updated my question. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now I get it. First, I would NEVER recommend that you use the Microsoft native tools to do partitioning. I see people with WAY too many problems.

Download Easeus here: http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm

Then once you open it, Click "Resize/Move Partition" in the left pane. Once the new window opens, you will pull the slider from the very right (the round dot) back to the right leaving the free white space as in the screenshot. Hit OK, then apply the changes (the check mark at the top).

After it is committed, make your new partition in the free space using Easeus or the Windows Disk Manager.

[image]

This is a very stable program and operation, and should not lose any data or affect your recovery partition. I have never had this program, or any like it fail in 17 years. That said, any disk manipulation has a chance of going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can see a 12GB of space Disk1. Is that the Recovery Drive? I really don't want to loose the Recovery Drive of mine. As I need to call Dell again and don't want to mess with them if something wrong goes. Appreciate your help.

Comment: As you look at my similar screenshot, you should have three partitions on your one disk instead of my one. You want to Resize, then click the large partition, and pull its slider to the right until you get the size you want. Click OK, and apply. Don't touch either of the two small partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to shrink Disk. I have the same laptop (bought about 3 weeks ago), i used O&O Defrag to Relocate Permanent Files (bootsector i think) and then i was able to shrink the disk. Also you will need to turn Off Paging, Virtual memory on the Partition you are trying to shrink, so that there are no OPEN files when you are shrinking, as open files cannot be moved.

When you use O&O Defrag, it will show you a multi-colored representation of your partition in which one particular color will be for non movable files, you will need to do something about those files.

For me they were in "System Volume Information", and i needed to turn off "Disk backup" and some more things to delete those files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will this lead to loosing my Recovery partition? Can you share the disk management screenshot (If no issues)