# Dell XPS 15z/ L511Z merging partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, dell-xps

i have a situation here, i bought a new dell xps 15z and was successful in making drive partitions through the help of this site ([Dell XPS 15 L502X hard drive Partition](https://superuser.com/questions/313082/dell-xps-15-l502x-hard-drive-partition))

now i have 
drive C with 100.55gb and a new volume with 578.45gb

im planning to use EaseUS again to undo this and resize my drive C but im scared i might cause damage to my drive, **is there a proper way to undo this and transfer the remaining 78.45gb from the new volume back to my drive C again? please help**

Answer (score 0):

A simple batch file could do the trick, though it may take some time, make a new file ANYWHERE (on your C: drive of course) and name it "transfer.bat", then copy this code into it by right clicking and pressing edit;

> @echo off
>
> rem xcopy a: b: /s /e
>
> set a=0
>
> set b=0
>
> title Transfer v1.0
>
> :main
>
> cls
>
> echo Enter the new drive volume letter without the dash, just the letter:
>
> set /p a=
>
> if %a%==0 goto main
>
> :confirm
>
> cls
>
> echo Windows is about to copy drive %a%: and store it into drive c:, continue?
>
> set /p b=Y/N:
>
> if %b%==Y goto yes
>
> if %b%==y goto yes
>
> if %b%==N goto no
>
> if %b%==n goto no
>
> goto confirm
>
> :no
>
> echo Cancelled
>
> echo.
>
> echo Press any button to leave...
>
> pause>nul
>
> exit
>
> :yes
>
> echo Copying...
>
> xcopy %a%: c: /s /e
>
> echo Complete!
>
> echo.
>
> echo Press any key to close...
>
> pause>nul

Save it then run it, all from there is what you type in, please note to be safe this will COPY your drive, you may delete it afterwards, but both directories will be merged to the C: drive.